# PoseStamped and Pose type difference

Tags: ros, pose

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know the difference between pose types of *PoseStamped* and *Pose* from geometry_msgs. Which one is better and/or in which situation one is better over another?

Why I always got problem when using PoseStamped, perhaps there are some requirements before we can use it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12438/posestamped-and-pose-type-difference/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Pose is the x,y,z position and quaternion orientation of the robot, a `rosmsg show Pose` reveals:

```
[geometry_msgs/Pose]:
geometry_msgs/Point position
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
  float64 w
```

While PoseStamped is simply a Pose message with the standard ROS header:

```
[geometry_msgs/PoseStamped]:
Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
  geometry_msgs/Point position
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
  geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
    float64 x
    float64 y
    float64 z
    float64 w
```

I think it depends on which stack you are using for which message is used, and I believe that PoseStamped is largely preferred because it includes the coordinate frame_id of the given Pose, as well as the time stamp that that Pose is valid.

On the other hand, if you don't need time information (say you are storing a time-independant Path), you could use an array of Poses, which would not need the additional header information.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PoseStamped contains a `Header`. A `header` contains 3 fields, `frame_id`, `stamp`, and `seq` (automatically filled in by ROS). A Pose message does not contain a header. PoseStamped is typically more regularly used because it provides additional useful information.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6